# gpg error installing docker on debian stretch

Tags: debian, docker, gpg

I followed these instructions for installing `docker` on debian 9.11 "stretch"

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

My file `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this

```
deb http://repo.myloc.de/debian stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://repo.myloc.de/debian stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://repo.myloc.de/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://repo.myloc.de/debian-security stretch/updates main

deb http://repo.myloc.de/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://repo.myloc.de/debian stretch-updates main

deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
#deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

The  command

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
```

gives

```
OK
```

but `apt update` results in

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker Release: The following signatures were invalid: 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
W: Failed to fetch https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/dists/docker/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am confused by the mentioning of `ubuntu` there, but probably that's fine.

EDIT: additional information requested in a comment

```
> uname -a
Linux b028 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1 (2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

> grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.save:deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12 wheezy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12 wheezy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12 wheezy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12 wheezy main
```

The content of the `sources.list.d` directory could be remnants that are wrong. Probably, I have to delete them.

Comment: Welcome, could you add the output of `uname -a` and `grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` ,please.

Comment: @GAD3R looks like I have outdated sources in the directory. Would you reckon it is save to simply delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you need to remove the docker repository under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (It is not a valid docker repo, it is an url to docker installation script):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list{,.save}
```

Then edit your `sources.list`:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

Change the following line:

```
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

to

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

Comment: works great, thanks